# How to import offline conversion tracking with GCLID?

Tags: google-ads-api

I want to import offline sales tracking on the Google AdWords.

I have downloaded the sample CSV template containing the column with the name GCLID.

But I am in the confusion that from where I get the different GCLID actually?

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

In order to import offline conversions into your adwords account:
1. You need to define a conversion in your adwords account.

2. you need to capture the gclid variable that google will send with each click and record it with each conversion happening on your system (i assume, you are an affiliate and you will have to find a way to forward the gclid to the affiliate tracking url subid). ex: `affurl.com?affid=yourid&offerid=9787&aff_sub=gclidvalue`
3. then you need to prepare the excel sheet according to the template provided by adwords

   - Pay attention to the timezone / timestamps
   - You need to be very precise as they will reject data that is not suitable
4. Upload the file
5. You need to repeat this process every day / week.

there are tools that can automate part of this process, but unfortunately the upload process is manual. 
good luck

Comment: This is correct.  Please see our help center for complete details.  https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/7012522

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup the `offline conversion tracking` to be able to retrieve the GCLID in your AdWords Account.

See below for more details.

https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/7012522